# Custom TCP / XML messaging in C++

Tags: c++, xml

I am interested in hearing views on this new Module I am adding to an existing system to handle sale items from a 3rd party Software system. This system sends (XML) messages to our system, we need to look up our database and sell the item if present.

Before I continue going down the route I am, I would like opinions on the approach I am taking (be it right or wrong). I am restricted to using Visual Studio 6.0, non MFC application.

The code will start in RunSCO and proceeds from here.

A message like so will arrive:

```xml
<Layer Name="CORE">
  <Message Name="SCOItem" SCO="true">
    <Items>
     <Item PLU="101158489212" />
    </Items>
  </Message>
</Layer>
```

This will be picked up in the loop in `SCO_Next_Item() @ string Msg = g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->HandleSCOMessage();`. From here we process the message and dispatch the correct method, which then replies with the correct XML response message.

There are many message types we can get `<Message Name="SCOItem"` or `<Message Name="SCOTender"` etc, I am handling these by reading the Name and mapping this to a function pointer.

```cpp
// NewModule_CORE.cpp: implementation of the NewModule_CORE class.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "NewModule_CORE.h"
#include "MyCompanyMessaging.h"
#include "MyCompanyMFController.h"
#include "MyCompanyEposAddin.h"
#include "Tenders.h"
#include "MyCompanySHPLink.h"

extern CMyCompanySHPLink *SHPHook;
extern Tenders *tenderClass;
extern MyCompanyEposAddin *cEposAddins;
extern CMyCompanyMessaging g_MyCompanyMessaging;
extern CMyCompanyMFController *g_pclsMyCompanyMFController;
extern StockItem       St;

typedef struct
{
    int iEndThread;
} INFOPARAMS, *PINFOPARAMS;
extern INFOPARAMS infoParams;

typedef struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS EXCEPTION_POINTERS, *PEXCEPTION_POINTERS;
int __cdecl RecordExceptionInfo(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS data, const char *Message);

extern VOID SHPHeartBeat_Thread( PVOID pvoid ); //Single cable thread
extern void WriteMyCompanyLog(char *cTextToWrite);
extern bool String_replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to);
extern void _Log_Sales_Entry_Exit(char *c); 
extern void HowMade();

extern void Get94CodeInfo(char *);
extern int Check_Open_Ean(char *);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Construction/Destruction
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

NewModule_CORE::NewModule_CORE()
{
    g_pclsMyCompanyMFController = NULL;

    if ((g_pclsMyCompanyMFController = new CMyCompanyMFController())!=NULL)
    {
        g_MyCompanyMessaging.Init();

        g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->MCSendFTVersionNo();

        char cTheTillNo[3] = {0};
        sprintf( cTheTillNo, "%02d", (int)_Get_Terminal_Number() );
        g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->SetMsgID( "DTY" );
        g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->GUISendFTTerminalNo( cTheTillNo );
    }

    WriteMyCompanyVersions();

    cEposAddins = new MyCompanyEposAddin();

    tenderClass = new Tenders();

    tenderClass->LoadTenders();

    HowMade();

    _Get_Open_Ean();

    SHPHook = new CMyCompanySHPLink();
    Sleep((DWORD)100);
    _beginthread(SHPHeartBeat_Thread, 0, &infoParams);

    ResetForNextSale();
}

NewModule_CORE::~NewModule_CORE()
{
    if (g_pclsMyCompanyMFController!=NULL)
    {
        delete g_pclsMyCompanyMFController;
        g_pclsMyCompanyMFController=NULL;
    }
}

void NewModule_CORE::ResetForNextSale()
{
    SaleTotal = 0;
    SaleTotalPaid = 0;
    ItemCount = 0;
    blnSaleInProgress = false;
}

void NewModule_CORE::RunSCO()
{
    __try
    {
        SCO_Main( );
    }
    __except(RecordExceptionInfo(GetExceptionInformation(), "RunSCO"))
    {
        // Do nothing here - RecordExceptionInfo() has already done
        // everything that is needed. Actually this code won't even
        // get called unless you return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER from
        // the __except clause.
    }

    return;
}

void NewModule_CORE::SCO_Main()
{
    while(true) //Needs to be changed to use the Exit condition
    {
        this->SCO_Next_Sale();
        this->SCO_Next_Item();
        this->SCO_CompleteSale();
        this->ResetForNextSale();
    }
}

void NewModule_CORE::SCO_Next_Sale()
{
    blnSaleInProgress = true;
}

void NewModule_CORE::SCO_Next_Item()
{
    string strKey = "";

    while(blnSaleInProgress)
    {
        string Msg = g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->HandleSCOMessage();

        g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->DoEvents();

        if(Msg != "")
        {
            ProcessFunctionFromScoLayer(Msg);
        }

        Sleep((DWORD)10);
    }
}

void NewModule_CORE::SCO_CompleteSale()
{
    g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->SCOSendEndTransaction("123456");
}

bool NewModule_CORE::ProcessFunctionFromScoLayer(string Msg)
{
    CMarkup XmlMsg;

    XmlMsg.SetDoc(Msg);
    XmlMsg.FindElem( "Layer" );
    XmlMsg.IntoElem();
    XmlMsg.FindElem( "Message" );

    string strFunctionToExecute = XmlMsg.GetAttrib( "Name" );

    struct STRUCTMESSHANDLERS {
        char cName[30];
        void  (NewModule_CORE::*pHandler)(CMarkup);
    };

    #define NUM_SCOMESSAGES 2

    STRUCTMESSHANDLERS aMessHandlers[NUM_SCOMESSAGES] = {
        { "SCOItem",    NewModule_CORE::HandleSCOItem   },
        { "SCOTender",  NewModule_CORE::SCOTender   },
    };

    if (strFunctionToExecute != "")
    {
        void  (NewModule_CORE::*pVPHandler)(CMarkup);

        for (int iMessageNo=0; iMessageNo<NUM_SCOMESSAGES; iMessageNo++)
        {
            if (strncmp(strFunctionToExecute.c_str(),
                        aMessHandlers[iMessageNo].cName  ,
                        strlen(aMessHandlers[iMessageNo].cName))==0)
            {
                pVPHandler = aMessHandlers[iMessageNo].pHandler;
                (this->*pVPHandler)( XmlMsg );

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void NewModule_CORE::HandleSCOItem(CMarkup XmlMsg) 
{
    XmlMsg.ResetPos();
    XmlMsg.FindElem( "Layer" );
    XmlMsg.IntoElem();
    XmlMsg.FindElem( "Message" );
    XmlMsg.IntoElem();
    XmlMsg.FindElem( "Items" );
    XmlMsg.IntoElem();

    if(XmlMsg.FindElem( "Item" ))
    {
        string strPLU = XmlMsg.GetAttrib( "PLU" );

        ItemInfo Item = GetItemInfo((char *)strPLU.c_str());

        if(Item.bItemFound)
        {
            SCOprintf("Sale Item\r\n");
            char cPrice[50] = {0};
            sprintf(cPrice, "%ld", St.Price[0]);

            SaleTotal += St.Price[0];

            double Qty = 1.0;
            char cText[100] = {0};
            char cUnitPrice[20] = {0};
            char cFullPrice[50] = {0};
            _LongPrice_To_Char(St.Price[0], cUnitPrice);
            _LongPrice_To_Char(St.Price[0], cFullPrice);
            sprintf(cText, "% -14s %10.3f %10s %10s", Item.cItemCode, Qty, cUnitPrice, cFullPrice);
            MyCompany_Write_Journal("SALE", cText, NO_DATE);

            g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->SCOSendItemSold((char *)strPLU.c_str(), St.Des, cPrice);
            ItemCount++;

            this->SendTotals();
        }
        else
        {
            if(IsLoyaltyCard(strPLU))
            {
                SCOprintf("PLU ISLOYALTY\r\n");
                g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->SCOSendLoyaltyCardSet((char *)strPLU.c_str());
            }
            else
            {
                SCOprintf("NOT FOUND Sale Item\r\n");
                g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->SCOSendItemNotFound((char *)strPLU.c_str());
            }
        }
    }
}

void NewModule_CORE::SCOTender(CMarkup XmlMsg) 
{
    //blnSaleInProgress = false;

    XmlMsg.ResetPos();
    XmlMsg.FindElem( "Layer" );
    XmlMsg.IntoElem();
    XmlMsg.FindElem( "Message" );
    XmlMsg.IntoElem();

    if(XmlMsg.FindElem( "Values" ))
    {
        string strAmount = XmlMsg.GetAttrib( "Amount" );
        string strTenderType = XmlMsg.GetAttrib( "TenderType" );

        if(StringToUpper(strTenderType) == "CASH")
        {
            char cSaleTotal[25] = {0};
            sprintf(cSaleTotal, "%ld", SaleTotal);
            string sSaleTotal = cSaleTotal;

            if(sSaleTotal == strAmount)
            {
                //Sale Complete
                g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->SCOSendTenderAccepted((char *)strTenderType.c_str(), (char *)strAmount.c_str());

                SaleTotalPaid = atol(strAmount.c_str());

                this->SendTotals();

                blnSaleInProgress = false;
            }
        }           
    }
}


bool NewModule_CORE::IsLoyaltyCard(string strPLU)
{
    if(strPLU.find("123456") != std::string::npos)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

NewModule_CORE::ItemInfo NewModule_CORE::GetItemInfo(char *cPLU)
{
    bool    bGotItemInfo = false;
    long    lPluRec;
    char    cBasePLU[15] = {0};
    bool    bOpenItem = false;

    ItemInfo m_ItemInfo = {0};

    if ((strlen(cPLU) >= 20 && strncmp(cPLU,"94",2) == 0))
    {
        Get94CodeInfo(cPLU);
    }
    else
    {
        // get plu record from stock file
        MakePLUCode( cPLU );
    }

    strncpy( cBasePLU, cPLU, 13 );
    if (Check_Open_Ean(cBasePLU)) {
        // Open Ean Exaction.
        _Extract_Open_Ean(cBasePLU);
        lPluRec = _Find_Plu(cBasePLU);
        bOpenItem = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lPluRec = _Find_Plu(cPLU);
    }
    if (lPluRec>0)
    {
        _Stock(STOCK_PRIM,MyCompany_READONLY, lPluRec);

        // St global structure has product details now
        memset( m_ItemInfo.cDescription, 0, 40 );
        strncpy( m_ItemInfo.cDescription, St.Des, 35 );

        memset( m_ItemInfo.cItemCode, 0, 20 );
        memset( m_ItemInfo.cBaseCode, 0, 20 );

        if (!bOpenItem)
        {
            strncpy( m_ItemInfo.cItemCode, cPLU, 15 );
        }
        else
        {
            strncpy( m_ItemInfo.cItemCode, cPLU, 15 );
            strncpy( m_ItemInfo.cBaseCode, cBasePLU, 15 );
        }

        m_ItemInfo.lFilePrice = St.Price[0];

        m_ItemInfo.iWeighed = St.Weighed;   

        m_ItemInfo.iDept    = atoi(St.Dept);
        m_ItemInfo.iArtGrp  = St.ProdLabel;

        m_ItemInfo.iStopped = St.Stop;      

        m_ItemInfo.bItemFound = true;   
    }
    else
    {
        // PLU not on file
        m_ItemInfo.bItemFound = false;
    }

    return m_ItemInfo;
}

void NewModule_CORE::MakePLUCode(char *cPLU)
{
    int             i,
                    Max;

    _Filter(cPLU, 0);

    Max = (int) _Control(MAX_PLU_LENGTH, TRUE);
    if (Max <= 0 || Max > 14)
        Max = 14;

    if (_Control(ZERO_FILL_PLUS, FALSE)) {
        while ((int) (strlen(cPLU)) < Max) {
            i = strlen(cPLU);
            _strrev(cPLU);
            cPLU[i] = 48;
            cPLU[i + 1] = 0;
            _strrev(cPLU);
        }
    }
    if (_Control(REMOVE_LEADING_ZEROS, FALSE)) {
        while (cPLU[0] == 48) {
            i = strlen(cPLU) - 1;
            if (!i)
                return;
            _strrev(cPLU);
            cPLU[i] = 0;
            _strrev(cPLU);
        }
    }
    i = strlen(cPLU);
    if (i > Max)
        cPLU[Max] = 0;

    return;
}

void NewModule_CORE::SCOprintf(string s)
{
    printf(s.c_str());
}

void NewModule_CORE::SendTotals()
{
    char cTotals[25] = {0};
    sprintf(cTotals, "%ld", SaleTotal);

    char cItemCount[20] = {0};
    sprintf(cItemCount, "%ld", ItemCount);

    int iBalanceDue = SaleTotal - SaleTotalPaid;
    char cBalDue[20] = {0};
    sprintf(cBalDue, "%ld", iBalanceDue);

    g_pclsMyCompanyMFController->SCOSendTotals(cBalDue,cTotals,cItemCount);
}

string NewModule_CORE::StringToUpper(string strToConvert)
{
    std::transform(strToConvert.begin(), strToConvert.end(), strToConvert.begin(), ::toupper);

    return strToConvert;
}
```

**Header File**

```cpp
// NewModule_CORE.h: interface for the NewModule_CORE class.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#if !defined(AFX_NewModule_CORE_H__68E7990D_E328_418E_8A17_8DEB9EB9087A__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_NewModule_CORE_H__68E7990D_E328_418E_8A17_8DEB9EB9087A__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

#include <string>
#include "Markup.h"

using namespace std;

class NewModule_CORE  
{
public:
    struct ItemInfo
    {
        char    cDescription[40];
        char    cItemCode[20];
        long    lPrice;
        long    lFilePrice;
        int     iWeighed;
        int     iDept;
        short   iArtGrp;
        int     iStopped;
        int     iQtyRequired;
        int     iAgeRequired;
        int     iSCOTag;
        bool    bCustomerCard;
        char    cLastScannedVoucher[20];
        char    cBaseCode[20];
        bool    bItemFound;
    };

public:
    void NewModule_CORE::RunSCO();
    NewModule_CORE();
    virtual ~NewModule_CORE();

private:

    void NewModule_CORE::SCO_Main();
    void NewModule_CORE::SCO_Next_Item();

    ItemInfo NewModule_CORE::GetItemInfo(char *cPLU);
    void NewModule_CORE::MakePLUCode(char *cPLU);
    bool NewModule_CORE::ProcessFunctionFromScoLayer(string strFunc);
    bool NewModule_CORE::IsLoyaltyCard(string strPLU);
    void NewModule_CORE::HandleSCOItem(CMarkup strMsg);
    void NewModule_CORE::ResetForNextSale();
    void NewModule_CORE::SCOTender(CMarkup XmlMsg);
    string NewModule_CORE::StringToUpper(string strToConvert);
    void NewModule_CORE::SCO_CompleteSale();
    void NewModule_CORE::SCO_Next_Sale();
    void NewModule_CORE::SendTotals();


    void NewModule_CORE::SCOprintf(string s);

    int SaleTotal;
    int SaleTotalPaid;
    int ItemCount;
    bool blnSaleInProgress;
};

#endif // !defined(AFX_NewModule_CORE_H__68E7990D_E328_418E_8A17_8DEB9EB9087A__INCLUDED_)
```

**Other Methods**

```cpp
int MyCompanyMF::SCOSendLoyaltyCardSet( char *cPLU )
{
    int  iSentMsg = 0;
    char cGUIMsg[1024] = { 0 };
    MyCompanyMFSCOLayer *pclsMFGL;

    if (IsInitialised())
    {
        pclsMFGL = (MyCompanyMFSCOLayer*)pclsMFGUILayer;

        // construct message
        if (pclsMFGL->CreateMsgFTSCOLoyaltyCardSet( pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, cGUIMsg, cPLU ))
        {
            GUISaveMessage( cGUIMsg, false );
            pclsMFLogFile->LogToFile( cGUIMsg );
            if (SendMessage( cGUIMsg ))
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Success" );
                iSentMsg = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Failed" );
            }
        }
    }

    return iSentMsg;
}

int MyCompanyMF::SCOSendItemNotFound( char *cPLU )
{
    int  iSentMsg = 0;
    char cGUIMsg[1024] = { 0 };
    MyCompanyMFSCOLayer *pclsMFGL;

    if (IsInitialised())
    {
        pclsMFGL = (MyCompanyMFSCOLayer*)pclsMFGUILayer;

        // construct message
        if (pclsMFGL->CreateMsgFTSCOItemNotFound( pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, cGUIMsg, cPLU ))
        {
            GUISaveMessage( cGUIMsg, false );
            pclsMFLogFile->LogToFile( cGUIMsg );
            if (SendMessage( cGUIMsg ))
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Success" );
                iSentMsg = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Failed" );
            }
        }
    }

    return iSentMsg;


}

int MyCompanyMF::SCOSendTenderAccepted( char *cTenderType, char *cAmount )
{
    int  iSentMsg = 0;
    char cGUIMsg[1024] = { 0 };
    MyCompanyMFSCOLayer *pclsMFGL;

    if (IsInitialised())
    {
        pclsMFGL = (MyCompanyMFSCOLayer*)pclsMFGUILayer;

        // construct message
        if (pclsMFGL->CreateMsgFTSCOTenderAccepted( pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, cGUIMsg, cTenderType, cAmount ))
        {
            GUISaveMessage( cGUIMsg, false );
            pclsMFLogFile->LogToFile( cGUIMsg );
            if (SendMessage( cGUIMsg ))
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Success" );
                iSentMsg = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Failed" );
            }
        }
    }

    return iSentMsg;


}

int MyCompanyMF::SCOSendItemSold( char *cPLU, char *cDes, char *cPrice)
{
    int  iSentMsg = 0;
    char cMsg[1024] = { 0 };
    MyCompanyMFSCOLayer *pclsMFSCOL;

    if (IsInitialised())
    {
        pclsMFSCOL = (MyCompanyMFSCOLayer*)pclsMFGUILayer;

        // construct message
        if (pclsMFSCOL->CreateMsgFTSCOItemSold( pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, cMsg, cPLU, cDes, cPrice ))
        {
            GUISaveMessage( cMsg, false );
            pclsMFLogFile->LogToFile( cMsg );
            if (SendMessage( cMsg ))
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Success" );
                iSentMsg = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Failed" );
            }
        }
    }

    return iSentMsg;


}

int MyCompanyMF::SCOSendTotals( char *cBalDue, char *cTotalAmount, char *cItemCount)
{
    int  iSentMsg = 0;
    char cMsg[1024] = { 0 };
    MyCompanyMFSCOLayer *pclsMFSCOL;

    if (IsInitialised())
    {
        pclsMFSCOL = (MyCompanyMFSCOLayer*)pclsMFGUILayer;

        // construct message
        if (pclsMFSCOL->CreateMsgFTSCOTotals( pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, cMsg, cBalDue, cTotalAmount, cItemCount))
        {
            GUISaveMessage( cMsg, false );
            pclsMFLogFile->LogToFile( cMsg );
            if (SendMessage( cMsg ))
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Success" );
                iSentMsg = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Failed" );
            }
        }
    }

    return iSentMsg;


}

int MyCompanyMF::SCOSendEndTransaction( char *cTransNo)
{
    int  iSentMsg = 0;
    char cMsg[1024] = { 0 };
    MyCompanyMFSCOLayer *pclsMFSCOL;

    if (IsInitialised())
    {
        pclsMFSCOL = (MyCompanyMFSCOLayer*)pclsMFGUILayer;

        // construct message
        if (pclsMFSCOL->CreateMsgFTEndTransaction( pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, cMsg, cTransNo ))
        {
            GUISaveMessage( cMsg, false );
            pclsMFLogFile->LogToFile( cMsg );
            if (SendMessage( cMsg ))
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Success" );
                iSentMsg = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                pclsMFLogFile->LogResultToFile( "SendResult: Failed" );
            }
        }
    }

    return iSentMsg;


}



int MyCompanyMFSCOLayer::CreateMsgFTSCOItemSold( MyCompanyPOSCore *pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, char *cMsg, char *cPLU, char *cDesc, char *cPrice)
{
    const char  *pMsg = NULL;
    char        cAttrName[100] = {0};
    char        cAttrValue[200] = {0};
    long        lMsgLen = 0;
    static char cLastMsg[300] = {0};

    MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder *pXMLBuild = new MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardProlog( "SCO", "CORE", "ItemSold" );

    strncpy( cAttrName, cPLU, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "PLU", cAttrName );  

    strncpy( cAttrName, cDesc, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "Description", cAttrName );  

    strncpy( cAttrName, cPrice, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "Price", cAttrName );    

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardEpiLog();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    pMsg = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsg();
    strncpy( cMsg, pMsg, lMsgLen+1 );

    delete pXMLBuild;

    return (int)lMsgLen;        // length of msg > 0 indicates success
}

int MyCompanyMFSCOLayer::CreateMsgFTEndTransaction( MyCompanyPOSCore *pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, char *cMsg, char *cTransNo )
{
    const char  *pMsg = NULL;
    char        cAttrName[100] = {0};
    char        cAttrValue[200] = {0};
    long        lMsgLen = 0;
    static char cLastMsg[300] = {0};

    MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder *pXMLBuild = new MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardProlog( "SCO", "CORE", "EndTransaction" );

    strncpy( cAttrName, cTransNo, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "TransactionID", cAttrName );

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardEpiLog();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    pMsg = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsg();
    strncpy( cMsg, pMsg, lMsgLen+1 );

    delete pXMLBuild;

    return (int)lMsgLen;    
}


int MyCompanyMFSCOLayer::CreateMsgFTSCOTotals( MyCompanyPOSCore *pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, char *cMsg, char *cBalDue, char *cTotalAmount, char *cItemCount)
{
    const char  *pMsg = NULL;
    char        cAttrName[100] = {0};
    char        cAttrValue[200] = {0};
    long        lMsgLen = 0;
    static char cLastMsg[300] = {0};

    MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder *pXMLBuild = new MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardProlog( "SCO", "CORE", "Totals" );

    strncpy( cAttrName, cBalDue, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "BalanceDue", cAttrName );   

    strncpy( cAttrName, cTotalAmount, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "TotalAmount", cAttrName );  

    strncpy( cAttrName, cItemCount, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "ItemCount", cAttrName );    

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardEpiLog();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    pMsg = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsg();
    strncpy( cMsg, pMsg, lMsgLen+1 );

    delete pXMLBuild;

    return (int)lMsgLen;        // length of msg > 0 indicates success
}

int MyCompanyMFSCOLayer::CreateMsgFTSCOItemNotFound( MyCompanyPOSCore *pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, char *cMsg, char *cPLU)
{
    const char  *pMsg = NULL;
    char        cAttrName[100] = {0};
    char        cAttrValue[200] = {0};
    long        lMsgLen = 0;
    static char cLastMsg[300] = {0};

    MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder *pXMLBuild = new MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardProlog( "SCO", "CORE", "ItemNotFound" );

    strncpy( cAttrName, cPLU, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "PLU", cAttrName );  

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardEpiLog();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    pMsg = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsg();
    strncpy( cMsg, pMsg, lMsgLen+1 );

    delete pXMLBuild;

    return (int)lMsgLen;        // length of msg > 0 indicates success
}

int MyCompanyMFSCOLayer::CreateMsgFTSCOTenderAccepted( MyCompanyPOSCore *pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, char *cMsg, char *cTenderType, char *cAmount)
{
    const char  *pMsg = NULL;
    char        cAttrName[100] = {0};
    char        cAttrValue[200] = {0};
    long        lMsgLen = 0;
    static char cLastMsg[300] = {0};

    MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder *pXMLBuild = new MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardProlog( "SCO", "CORE", "TenderAccepted" );

    strncpy( cAttrName, cTenderType, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "TenderType", cAttrName );   

    strncpy( cAttrName, cAmount, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "Amount", cAttrName );   

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardEpiLog();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    pMsg = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsg();
    strncpy( cMsg, pMsg, lMsgLen+1 );

    delete pXMLBuild;

    return (int)lMsgLen;        // length of msg > 0 indicates success
}

int MyCompanyMFSCOLayer::CreateMsgFTSCOLoyaltyCardSet( MyCompanyPOSCore *pclsMyCompanyPOSCore, char *cMsg, char *cPLU)
{
    const char  *pMsg = NULL;
    char        cAttrName[100] = {0};
    char        cAttrValue[200] = {0};
    long        lMsgLen = 0;
    static char cLastMsg[300] = {0};

    MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder *pXMLBuild = new MyCompanyXMLMsgBuilder();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardProlog( "SCO", "CORE", "LoyaltyCard" );

    strncpy( cAttrName, cPLU, 99 );
    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddAttributeAndValue( "Card", cAttrName ); //        Card="1234567890123"

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->AddStandardEpiLog();

    lMsgLen = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsgLen();
    pMsg = pXMLBuild->GetXMLMsg();
    strncpy( cMsg, pMsg, lMsgLen+1 );

    delete pXMLBuild;

    return (int)lMsgLen;        
}
```

Comment: "I am restricted to using Visual Studio 6.0" - seriously? Visual Studio 6.0 is nearly old enough to vote and predates C++ standardization. Why on earth is your company still using it?

Comment: Legacy system that still has a lot of CORE business logic.

Comment: When you say "I would like opinions on the approach I am taking", what part of the approach is flexible? I might be misunderstanding, but it seems to me like this much is fixed: "This system sends (XML) messages to our system, we need to look up our database and sell the item if present." Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: You are correct, its restricted to what you say, i just wanted to see if I#m going about it the right way and no obvious alarm bells are set off.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick cop-out comments, since I've not taken the time to actually understand what's happening here:

One thing I just happened to notice is the classic

```
if(strPLU.find("123456") != std::string::npos)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

One should just write

```
return strPLU.find("123456") != std::string::npos;
```

There was also the very oddly formatted

```
int             i,
                Max;
```

which raised an eyebrow.